# class file for java.sql.Connection not found error on updating to Java 11 from Java 8

Tags: java, sql, gradle, classnotfoundexception, ibatis

I'm in process of upgrading a Java 8 Gradle module-based project to Java 11.This is the class structure where error is seen :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLClientInfoException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner;

public class someclass{
    public someclass(Connection conn) {
        setConnconnection(conn);
    }
    
    public Connection getConnection() {
        return m_conn;
    }

    public void setConnconnection(Connection conn) {
        m_conn = conn;
    }
    
    public void populateDefault() throws ConfigurationException {
        
        <... some lines ...>
    
        ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(m_conn);
        sr.setAutoCommit(true);
        sr.setStopOnError(true);
        sr.runScript(<script>);
    }
    
    private Connection m_conn;
}
```

On `gradle build`, I get the error :

```
error: cannot access Connection
               ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(m_conn);
                                 ^
 class file for java.sql.Connection not found
```

The module-info.java for this module is ,

```
open module somemodule {
    requires java.sql;
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires org.apache.ibatis;
    requires org.xerial.sqlite;
    < other req>
}
```

I'm not able to see the reason behind this error. Any insights would be very helpful.

Comment: What is `ScriptRunner` and which module does it come from?

Comment: @Andreas That comes from the ibatis module. I have now added the imports section of the class file to my question.